# How to get a notification from Outlook 2007 when an e-mail with a specific body arrives

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I get a bunch of incoming e-mails containing error information from an ASP.NET web application. Each e-mail represents a specific exception thrown in the application. The exception is contained within the e-mail body.

I need my mail client, Outlook 2007, to notify me when an e-mail with a body containing a specific exception is received.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Tools` > `Rules`. A new window pops-up. Next check the "Stay up to date section".

[image: Rules Wizard]

I'd go for "Play a sound when I get messages from someone" or "Display mail from someone in the New Item Alert Window" but maybe one of the others would work for you too.

When clicking next, you can define parameters for when to trigger this action. (E.g. Certain string in body/subject, certain sender, etc.)